# get from collection and iterate over

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to return data with loop in api.
But you know foreach loop Asynchronous and my allData json object everytime is null. 
I want the json object not to be empty.
That's why... I want to make synchronous loop below

```
var allData = [];
router.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {

    var cursor = mdb.collection('USERS').find();
    cursor.forEach(function (doc) {
        allData.push(doc);
        console.log(doc);
    })
    console.log(allDaTa);
});
```

print :

```
[ ] //<-- my json object is null (allData) 
<br><br> 
{ 
    _id: 5830ce676b184b1210d66749,
    USERNAME: 'burakgumus'
}
```

i say again `<br><br>`
I want the json object not to be empty and i don't want to `cursor.toArray().<br>`

Comment: Are you using `mongoosejs`?

Comment: No, i'm using mongodb module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a callback function to your query. As it is an async call and will return the result later when you would have gone through the rest of your code:

```
var allData = [];
router.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {

    mdb.collection('USERS').find({}).toArray(function(err, cursor) {
        cursor.forEach(function (doc) {
            allData.push(doc);
            console.log(doc);
        });
        console.log(allDaTa);
        next();
    });

});
```

Comment: No its not same, look closely. I have created a `callback function` here. Just copy and paste and check it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Shaharyar's answer if you want a response you also have to call the .send() function on the response, i.e. res.send(allData)

```
var allData = [];
router.get('/user', function (req, res, next) {

mdb.collection('USERS').find({}).toArray(function(err, cursor) {
    cursor.forEach(function (doc) {
        allData.push(doc);
        console.log(doc);
    });
    console.log(allDaTa);
    res.send(allData);
    next();
});

});
```

Comment: Why doesnt exist normal loop?